# iOS App submission without 3x launch images but supporting iPhone 6 and iPhone 6plus

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

We are planing to submit an app supporting from iOS 7 . We might submit it in the month of April 2015. We are not currently planning to add 3x images. iPhone 6 and 6 plus are supported though.  We are not adding launch images in the iOS8+ category. We are adding only in iOS 7 and later in Xcode 6.

Given that scenario will our app be approved by Apple?. Please post if there is risk of rejection.

Comment: As an iOS App Developer, you should always release App with maximum support of devices whenever possible. What is the reason of not supporting iPhone 6 & 6 Plus?

Comment: @Raptor It is a big project adding launch screen introduces problem in many of the screens layout , esp where scroll view is involved with auto layouts. At the moment the default support works well for the screens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no issue in adding launch images just for the 1x and 2x although not highly recommended.

Recommendation from Apple

> **Support for a New Screen Scale** The iPhone 6 Plus uses a new Retina HD
>   display with a screen scale of 3.0. To provide the best possible
>   experience on these devices, include new artwork designed for this
>   screen scale.

**You can go ahead, there is no reason that apple would reject it.**

iOs will automatically choose whatever image is most suitable for that particular screen size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a rule which says that you can't submit an app which does not have launch images for some devices.

In fact we sent an app which had the situation like you explained here. And it was approved by Apple.

Answer (score -1):

We are not currently planning to add 3x images. iPhone 6 and 6 plus are supported though

==> Iphone 6+ support means including @3x images. (otherwise by default you mean by support which it provides by itself)

App won't be rejected.